# html 5 validation and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, validation

I have a quick question, I have a form and I have used the `required="required"` (HTML5 Validation) for my fields, and I have two buttons, RESET and SUBMIT, the validation should only work when the SUBMIT button is pressed, however when I click on the RESET button, which should clear the fields, still proceeds with the validation and prompting me that it is a required field, how can I assign the validation only to SUBMIT button.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPolNo" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Policy Number" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#C2C4CC" BorderStyle="Solid" Height="28px" 
    Width="135px" title="Enter Your Policy Number" required ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: I don't have any idea on how to do this

Comment: Paste it into the question window and format it as code.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPolNo" runat="server"  placeholder="Enter Policy Number" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#C2C4CC"  BorderStyle="Solid"   Height="28px" Width="135px" title="Enter Your Policy Number" required ></asp:TextBox>

Comment: there is my markup for one of my textbox, it is validated by two buttons even the reset button, I need it to be validated only by the submit button

Comment: I've added your markup to your question. We could do with seeing the whole form, along with buttons. I've no idea what your reset button code looks like.

Comment: Your code is missing a value for `required`.

Comment: Are you sure your Reset button is really Reset? Issue is not happening here: http://jsfiddle.net/83NTZ/ Please post markup for the buttons as well

Answer (score 0):

Use Dev Tools (F12) and/or "View Source" to inspect the Reset button. Pay attention to what it may be doing for `onclick`, and for what the `form` may be doing for `onsubmit` and it should help point you in the right direction.

If you copy and paste your "View Source" contents into SO we could better understand how your HTML is rendered. You may be using `input type="submit"` instead of `input type="reset"` for your "Reset" button, but no point in speculating without seeing your full code.